# What is the order of returned elements from the Redis command ZRANGEBYLEX

Tags: redis

What is the order of returned elements from the Redis command ZRANGEBYLEX? Or is it not defined?

Answer (score 1):

As the name says it is in lexicographical ordering.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test 0 a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e
(integer) 5
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX test - [z
1) "a"
2) "b"
3) "c"
4) "d"
5) "e"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX test [b [z
1) "b"
2) "c"
3) "d"
4) "e"
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test 0 aaaa
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX test [a [z
1) "a"
2) "aaaa"
3) "b"
4) "c"
5) "d"
6) "e"
```

In the last sample "a" is lexicographically lesser than "aaaa". Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand it uses lexicographical ordering to store stuff, but it does not state in the documentation whether the returned list has the same ordering.